# calculated adjacency matrix values ​can be automatically expected to factor 2

Tags: matrix, graphs-and-networks

```
n = {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 1 -> 6, 2 -> 6, 3 -> 6, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 2, 5 -> 6, 5 -> 3};

p = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};

m = Graph[Table[i, {i, 1, 6}], n, VertexLabels -> "Name"];

x = Normal[AdjacencyMatrix[m]]
```

Therefrom for example node number 1 adjacencymatrix is:

> {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1} etc.

Next I would like to automatically highlight these data which meets bigger then the 25% and this table arrange in according to rank with these codes:

```
serial = Range[Length[p]];
value = {200, 40, 30, 50, 5, 120};
percent = 100 N[value/Total[value]];
titel = {"nr.", "Name", "Value", "Percent", "Rank"};
rank = value /. Thread[# -> Ordering[#, All, Greater]] &@Union@value;
dt = Transpose[{serial, p, value, percent, rank}];
ord = Sort[dt, #1[[4]] > #2[[4]] &];
ov = 1 + Pick[ord[[All, 5]], Thread[ord[[All, 4]] >= 25]];
color = Rule[#, GrayLevel[0.78]] & /@ ov;

Grid[Prepend[ord, titel], Frame -> All, Spacings -> {4, 0.5}, Alignment -> {{Left, Left, Center, Center}, None}, Background -> {None, color}]
```

Output table gives me (also number 1 and 6) which value of adjacencymatrix that I would like to automatically multiply with 2!

I can only do it manuel form with these simple codes:

```
x2 = x*{2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2}
```

output

> {{0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0,
>      0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}

its also multiply number 1 and 6 adjacencymatrix with 2.
How can I make this last part automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to multiply by 2 those entries in the adjacency matrix that correspond to vertices whose calculated "percentages" are > 25.

Here is one way to do that (I will be using your own definitions of variables as you showed them in your question). First, the `Cases` statement selects those entries whose percent > 25 and returns a list of their original positions. Then we apply a "2x" function (`2#&`) to those selected elements in the original adjacency matrix `x`.

```
selected = Cases[ord, {position_, _, _, percent_ /; percent > 25, _} -> position];
MapAt[2 # &, x, List /@ selected]

(* Out:
{{0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, 
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
*)
```

Comment: perfect exactly what I want to do. Thanks @MarcoB

Comment: @usernew1 Excellent! I'm glad I could help. Perhaps you would consider formally accepting this answer then, by checking the gray check mark next to it. More in general I noticed that you have asked quite a few questions on this site, and received multiple answers, but you have never accepted any. You may want to go back and see if any of the answers to your previous questions are worth of an official accept as well, since this rewards the efforts of those that tried to help you.